# A LEFT OUTER JOIN with a ORDER BY '$x' is not sorting properly

Tags: mysql, left-join, sql-order-by

I have the following SELECT statement which SHOULD be returning the recordset ORDERED BY Last Name and it is not. I have checked to see if any blank characters/spaces are in the last name field and there isn't as they have all been trimmed using $last_name = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'LastName', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));.

```
 $query_PaidOrders = "SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `payment_received` = '1'";
$rs_PaidOrders=$conn->query($query_PaidOrders);

if($rs_PaidOrders === false){
    trigger_error('SQL error:'.$query_PaidOrders.' Error: '.$conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
else{
  while ($row_PaidOrders=$rs_PaidOrders->fetch_assoc()) {
    $PaidOrderId=$row_PaidOrders['order_id'];
    $query_select_events = "SELECT customers.last_name AS LASTNAME,
                        customers.first_name AS FIRSTNAME,
                        order_details.member_id AS MEMBERID,
                        order_details.event_type AS EVENTTYPE,
                        order_details.event_distance AS EVENTDISTANCE, 
                        order_details.keep_stats AS KEEPSTATS
                        FROM `order_details`

 LEFT OUTER JOIN customers ON order_details.member_id = customers.customer_id 

WHERE order_details.event_id = '$eid' AND order_details.counted_for_discount='1' AND order_details.ORDERNUM = '$PaidOrderId' ORDER BY LASTNAME ASC";

       $rs_events=$conn->query($query_select_events);

       if($rs_events === false){
       trigger_error('SQL error:'.$query_select_events.' Error: '.$conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
       }
       else{
            while($row_order_details=$rs_events->fetch_assoc()){
      $NAME = $row_order_details['LASTNAME'].", ".$row_order_details['FIRSTNAME'];  
      $member_id=$row_order_details['MEMBERID'];
      $event_type=$row_order_details['EVENTTYPE'];
      $event_distance=$row_order_details['EVENTDISTANCE'];
      $keep_stats=$row_order_details['KEEPSTATS'];
            ?>
            <tr>
               <td><?php echo "$NAME";?></td>
                etc...
```

My results are:
B..., H..., H..., S..., B..., R....

I am really stumped on this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to run the query directly against the DB in the mysql shell (outside PHP)?

Comment: When you say you checked for "blank" characters, do you just mean space and tab, or did you check for other non-printing characters as well?

Comment: luksch: I edited the original question to show that the Query is inside a while loop. 

UUeerdo:I edited the original question to show what I used on the $_POST to sanitize the input prior to inserting into the database.

Comment: Should I have combined this into 1 Query with multiple LEFT OUTER JOINS? Is it breaking because it is having to iterate on the first "While" before completing the second one?

Comment: [mcve] please. Incuding what is out of order. And code to cut & past & run. Also why would you not use one query? Also why would there be any order to the ids on which you loop? PS Google stackoverflow for what you are trying to do. (Besides trying to find the particular problem with this code via this question.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue WAS the fact that I did not combine everything into 1 query. Once I did that, the ORDER BY last name worked properly.